# Is it possible to show a user's Gmail notification on my website?

Tags: gmail, push

Is it possible to show a user's Gmail notification on my website?
I want to shownotifications of my user to them in my website. Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, if the user trusts you enough to store their gmail passwords with you.

For this, you need to store their username and password(application specific password, if enabled by them) and fetch their mail counts/mails/unread count etc using ur server technology functions and display it to the client.

Comment: Can you elaborate more.

Comment: Which server side technology are you using?